# HTML input "time" when typed only hours default minutes to be "00" on blur

Tags: javascript, dom, input, time

Occasionally we want to specify the minutes, but when we don't how do we default the minutes to "00" on blur when we just typed the hours? So in the example below, we typed "09" hours and want to move to other field but we still need to type "00" minutes to be a valid time.. is there any way to assume the minutes to be "00" when we just typed the hours on blur?

[image]

Comment: You likely won’t be able to _get_ the currently entered value with JS in the first place. Chrome just returns an empty string here, other browser probably do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a custom JavaScript function using the onfocusout event on the hour input, which then checks if the minute value is falsy and if it is, assigns it to 00.

More details on this event, MDN: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusout_event)

Comment: there is only one input="time"

Comment: @JoséSalgado input="time" requires full entry of both hours & minutes in order to assign a value to the input, which makes it impossible to get the hour. Alternative approach would be to have two inputs of type "number" which served this purpose. I would also discourage the use of input="time" since it is relatively new and unsupported by some older browsers.